What does it mean to write to the Register of an IC?
I am interested in using DP83TD510E as an ethernet PHY (side note, it seems to be one of the only ones I can find that supports 10Base-T-10L) and don't understand how it could be "programmed" from an MCU i.e. if this is wired up to an ESP32, what kind of code will need to be written to configure it?

In general, a "register" is a bit of memory in a machine that has a defined way of accessing it, and which is not "general-purpose scratchpad memory" (like the RAM in your PC), but has a specific purpose.
In this specific case, the way you access these MMD registers is via the MDIO (management data input/output) protocol on the pins of the same name. The way that is done is explained in the datasheet in section 6.3.9 Serial Management Interface.

To use the chip as an ethernet PHY you may not need to write anything into the PHY registers because it could already be factory-configured for a default operation. In order for the data to be used/processed, a MAC (microcontroller or microprocessor) that supports MII, RMII or RGMII along with dedicated driver(s) are needed. Not all ESP32s support MII/RMII/RGMII.
If you want to configure the IC for some special functions (e.g. GPIO config or MII or RMII mode) then you can use the SMI (MDC pin for clock and MDIO pin for data I/O) interface or the strap pins with manufacturer-defined pull-up or pull-down resistors. From section 6.4 onwards the config details are explained.

Hmmm that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a ton! :D
